# how to insert foreign key value through form in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to introduce new products in the ddbb, but i don't know how to add the foreign key.

here is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // create a variable
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $usos=$_POST['usos'];
    $peso=$_POST['peso'];
    $unidadcaja=$_POST['unidadcaja'];
    $precio=$_POST['precio'];
    $origen=$_POST['origen'];
    $tipoproducto=$_POST['tipodeproducto'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `producto` ( nombre, usos, peso, `unidad caja`, precio, origen, foto, `tipo de producto` ) VALUES ('$nombre', '$usos', '$peso', '$unidadcaja', '$precio', '$origen', '$file', '$tipoproducto')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } 
    else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}
?>    
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST" >     
    <p>
        <label for="tipoproducto">Tipo de producto</label>
        <?php
            $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
            $sql = "SELECT nombre FROM `TipoProducto`";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            echo "<select name='tipodeproducto'>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row['tipodeproducto']."'>" . $row['nombre'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is the error that give me:
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO `producto` ( nombre, usos, peso, `unidad caja`, precio, origen, foto, `tipo de producto` ) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''). Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`modacane_onena`.`producto`, CONSTRAINT `producto_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tipo de producto`) REFERENCES `TipoProducto` (`nombre`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: thanks, already changed! big mistake

Comment: You should really have error reporting on in your development server. The error appears to be that you are only selecting `nombre` from the table and not the `tipodeproducto` column.

Comment: If you reported the _exact_ text of the error message, then your primary issue is the absence of values (and so the "foreign key constraint fails" is pretty normal due to the empty value of `tipo de producto`). From there, you must first understand why you don't get the expected values. Start adding `print_r($_POST);` right after `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` and check the contents.